# Timepicker is not working in response from ajax request?

Tags: asp.net, timepicker

Timepicker is not working in response coming from ajax request.

Same Timepicker is working fine when i run Remark.aspx page individually.

It's not working only after binding ajax response in a div in **popup**.

Below is the jquery reequest:-

```
$.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "LMS/**Remark.aspx**",
                      data: {id:id, n:n},
                      cache:false,
                      success: function(response) {
                            $('#<%=content.ClientID %>').html(response);
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            alert('Some problem has been occured.');
                        }
                  });
```

Below is the div(this div is opening in **popup**) in which i am binding response:-

```
<div id="content" runat="server">
</div>
```

And if i m not opening popup it is working fine.**Problem is with popup only**.

Below is the timepicker which i m using:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/213311/Time-Picker-Ajax-Extender-Control

Any Help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The timepicker is inside div "content" or outside?

Comment: Timepicker is inside the form in Remarks.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

This timepicker will auto add a js block to initialize the timePicker. You can view page source to see that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Ajaxified.TimePicker, {"CloseOnSelection":true,"CssClass":"timepicker","HeaderCssClass":"header","ItemCssClass":"item","MinuteStep":15,"SelectedItemCssClass":"selecteditem","SelectedTabCssClass":"selectedtab","TabCssClass":"tab","TitleCssClass":"title"}, null, null, $get("TextBox2"));
});
//]]>
</script>
</form>
```

When get page content via ajax, below code is not triggered so the timepicker is not init correctly. Here you need to manually invoke your code "$(create(....." in your ajax success call back.